# Word ругается на отсутствие запятой

Tags: пунктуация

В процессе распечатки документа заполненные поля формы будут автоматически перенесены в документ.

Пишу документацию, Word ругается на отсутствие запятой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, Word принимает слово "заполненные" за причастие. А вообще, Word не авторитет для пунктуации.

Comment: Да, скорее всего. ...распечатки документа, заполненные... так похоже на оборот. Спасибо.

Comment: Это и есть причастие, только одиночное

Comment: А может, все же прилагательное? Какие поля - заполненные поля.

Answer (score 0):

Может, Вы его не поняли, иногда он подчёркивает, когда нужен пробел чуть больше, попробуйте после слова документа увеличить пробел. Запятой там нет.

Answer (score -1):

Впервые сталкиваюсь с такой ситуацией как у Вас. То, что поля формы могут автоматически переносится в документ меня удивляет больше. Приходилось перепечатывать весь текст целиком. Сидел до 12 часов ночи и размышлял над этим. 
Как можно самому сделать так, чтобы эту запятую понять или поставить в нужное место. Текст документа выделял полностью и копировал в открытый снова файл Microsoft Word. Только потом во весь текст документа вставлял значок Tab. Удалял все не нужные пробелы, что показывает этот значок. Выделял текст и в конце поля линейки нажимал на кнопку разметка страницы. После этого в поле числового значения шрифта появляется полная информация, то, что нужно сделать с документом. Нажимается по ширине страницы. 
У меня выходили поля формы документа до 6 страниц. Эта ситуация привела меня к тому, что только этот вариант здесь самый действенный.

Comment: Рад за Вас. Вот только моё первое предложение в вопросе не имеет отношения к Word'у. Всё равно спасибо.